# Select items with multiple tags and select details from other tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Thanks for the feedback on my lousy question. First time around here.

I'm working with SQlite and C# in Visual Studio.

This is a sample of the data in my tables:

```
TABLE: VIDEOS
-------------
ID  VideoName             VideoStarID       VideoCostarID
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   Casablanca                23                 43
2   Maltese Falcon            23                156
3   Matrix                   234                312
4   Matrix Reloaded          234                312
5   Matrix Revolutions       234                312
6   Pompeii                  312

TABLE: STARS
-------------
ID  StarName        
------------------------------
23  Humphrey Bogart 
43  Ingrid Bergman
156 Mary Astor
234 Keanu Reeves
312 Carrie-Anne Moss

TABLE: TAGS
-------------
ID  TagName     
------------------------------
1   Action
2   Classic
3   Drama
4   Horror
5   Thriller
6   Sci-Fi
7   Romance
8   Western
9   War
10  Film Noir
11  Comedy
12  History
13  Dystopia

TABLE: VIDEO_TAGS
-------------
VideoID     TagID   
------------------------------
1            2
1            5
1            7
1            9
2            1
2            2
2            5
3            1
3            5
3            6
3            13
4            1
4            5
4            6
4            13
5            1
5            5
5            6
5            13
6            12
6            3
```

I would like to select all movies starring Carrie-Anne Moss and Keanu Reeves with tags "Action", "Sci-Fi" and "Thriller". Actually, my query is gonna be more complex than that in the future, since I will have to be able to include parameters for year, studio, oscar nominations, oscars won, rating, etc.; but for now, the problem I am having is that I cannot get an output like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|VideoID |      VideoName    |   StarName   |    CostarName    |         Tags                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3    |Matrix             | Keanu Reeves | Carrie-Anne Moss | Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller, Dystopia |
|   4    |Matrix Reloaded    | Keanu Reeves | Carrie-Anne Moss | Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller, Dystopia |
|   4    |Matrix Revolutions | Keanu Reeves | Carrie-Anne Moss | Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller, Dystopia |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this (obviously) faulty query:

```
SELECT VIDEOS.ID, VIDEOS.VideoName, VIDEOS.StarID, VIDEOS.CostarID, STARS.StarName, GROUP_CONCAT(TAGS.Name) AS Tags
FROM VIDEOS
INNER JOIN STARS ON VIDEOS.StarID = STARS.ID
INNER JOIN VIDEO_TAGS ON VIDEOS.ID = VIDEO_TAGS.VideoID
INNER JOIN TAGS ON TAGS.ID = VIDEO_TAGS.TagID
WHERE 
VIDEOS.StarID = 234 AND 
VIDEOS.CostarID = 312 AND
VIDEO_TAGS = 1 AND
VIDEO_TAGS = 5 AND
VIDEO_TAGS = 6
```

The result is just one row. It does not get all the movies. I also don't get the tags as I want.

Hope this information helps. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing the DBMS, or having any sample data, or expected results, or seeing your existing (faulty) query, or having proper information about the schema, it _might_ be possible to get to the right answer, but you are making it really difficult for us. Take time to write your question with full details and clear explanations, and make it _really_ easy for people to help you. You're _much_ more likely to get a high number of good, useful answers if you do that, rather than one or two people with too much time on their hands having a bit of a guess.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for some guidance around asking a better more answerable question. Then consider editing and improving your question. Imagine you were trying to answer a question about a database you'd never seen before, and think of what kind of information you'd find useful. Then go and add that to your own question. We cannot read your screen, your disk...or your mind. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please, see my edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is this subquery:

```
  select distinct vt.videoid from video_tags vt
  where (select count(distinct tagid) from video_tags where videoid = vt.videoid and tagid in (1, 5, 6)) = 3
```

which gives you the ids of the videos that have all 3 tags that you need.
So use this:

```
select v.id VideoID, v.videoname VideoName, s1.starname StarName, s2.starname CoStarName,
  (select group_concat(tagname) from tags where id in (select tagid from video_tags where  videoid = v.id)) Tags 
from videos v inner join (
  select distinct vt.videoid from video_tags vt
  where (select count(distinct tagid) from video_tags where videoid = vt.videoid and tagid in (1, 5, 6)) = 3
) f
on f.videoid = v.id
inner join stars s1
on s1.id = v.videostarid
left join stars s2
on s2.id = v.videocostarid
where s1.id = 234 and s2.id = 312
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8YxHfAAZoMFeo1eGVr1Dp/4)

Comment: Thanks! This solution works great! Would you please tell me how to add another condition? I would need to add something like "Rating >= 5". The "Rating" column belongs to the same Videos table. How can I add this condition to this (already way above my head) query? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! Great solution. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only 1 row because you are missing the GROUP BY.
Also you need to use IN for the 3 TAGS.

```
SELECT VIDEOS.ID, VIDEOS.VideoName, VIDEOS.StarID, VIDEOS.CostarID, STARS.StarName, GROUP_CONCAT(TAGS.TagName) AS Tags
FROM VIDEOS
INNER JOIN STARS ON VIDEOS.StarID = STARS.ID
INNER JOIN VIDEO_TAGS ON VIDEOS.ID = VIDEO_TAGS.VideoID
INNER JOIN TAGS ON TAGS.ID = VIDEO_TAGS.TagID
WHERE 
VIDEOS.StarID = 234 AND 
VIDEOS.CostarID = 312 AND
VIDEO_TAGS.TagID IN (1,5,6)
GROUP BY VIDEOS.ID
```

[DBFiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kDStFZriy6wPLVNj5VykWe/1)